# Running excel macro via VB, returns run time error '429'

Tags: excel, vba, visual-studio

I'm able to run my macros manually in the excel sheet without an error, however when I run the code via VB, I get the "429" ActiveX error, which is related to the Outlook 15.0 reference. I have the outlook 15.0 object library referenced in both VB and the Excel file. Not sure what to do from here. Here's the code in VB:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.IO
Imports Microsoft.Office.Core
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop

Module module1

Sub Main()
    Dim bloomberg As String
    Dim xlApp
    Dim wkbk As String
    Dim macro As Strign
    Dim oWorkBook
    Dim boolexists As Boolean

    oWorkBook = Nothing


    bloomberg = "C:\blp\API\Office Tools\BloombergUI.xla"

    xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    'ReloadXLAddins(xlApp)
    'I want to see what happens
    xlApp.Visible = True
    ''Loading in the Bloomberg add-in
    xlApp.Workbooks.Open(bloomberg)

    ' Disable Excel UI elements
    xlApp.DisplayAlerts = True
    xlApp.AskToUpdateLinks = True
    xlApp.AlertBeforeOverwriting = True

    ' Iterate through the list by using nested loops. 
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To 5

        Select Case i
            Case 1
                wkbk = "E:\Screening\IPO Lockup"
                macro = "ipolockup"
            Case 2
                wkbk = "E:\Screening\UsBuybacksQ"
                macro = "UsBuybacksQ"
            Case 3
                wkbk = "E:\Screening\UsBuybacksY"
                macro = "UsBuybacksY"
            Case 4
                wkbk = "E:\Screening\GlobalBuybacksQ"
                macro = "GlobalBuybacksQ"
            Case 5
                wkbk = "E:\Screening\GlobalBuybacksY"
                macro = "GlobalBuybacksY"
        End Select


        oWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(wkbk)
        oWorkBook = xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromGuid("{2DF8D04C-5BFA-101B-BDE5-00AA0044DE52}", 0, 0)
        oWorkBook = xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromGuid("{2DF8D04C-5BFA-101B-BDE5-00AA0044DE52}", 0, 0)
        Thread.Sleep(Seconds(7))

        On Error Resume Next
        ' Run the macro
        xlApp.Run(macro)
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            ' Error occurred - just close it down.
            MsgBox("run macro Error occurred")
        End If
        Err.Clear()
        On Error GoTo 0
        Thread.Sleep(Seconds(20))
        ' Clean up and shut down
        oWorkBook.Close()
        oWorkBook = Nothing
    Next
    ' Don’t Quit() Excel if there are other Excel instances
    ' running, Quit() will shut those down also
    If xlApp.Workbooks.Count = 0 Then
        xlApp.Quit()
    End If
    xlApp.Quit()
    xlApp = Nothing

    MsgBox("Completed Email Draft Creation Succesfully")

End Sub

Private Function Seconds(ByVal value As Integer) As Integer
    Return value * 1000
End Function
```

and here is the snippet of code in the macro I'm trying to run in Excel:

```
Sub refreshed()
Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As New Outlook.Application


With Application
    .DisplayAlerts = False
     .Calculate
End With

i = Sheets("IPO").Range("numberofipo").Value
Sheets("IPO").Range("IPO").Select

Set rng = Nothing
Set rng = ActiveCell.Resize(i + 1, 16)

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .To = ""
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "Monthly IPO Data"
    .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
    .Save
End With
On Error GoTo 0

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

ThisWorkbook.Saved = True

End Sub
```

The error occurs on the line:

> Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

which leads me to believe it is related to the Outlook 15.0 object library.

Comment: Probably unrelated, but the next line will also give you an error unless you `Dim OutMail as Object ' or As Outlook.MailItem`

Comment: See if [THIS](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/828550) helps.

Comment: much appreciative!! It randomly started working this morning... i'll use your resource to try and prevent the problem from happening again. Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: Just as an update for anyone following, it seems that when you run the VB as an administrator the "429" error pops up. Not sure why that is a problem, but when I run it without admin privileges its works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems that when you run the VB as an administrator the "429" error pops up. Not sure why that is a problem, but when I run it without admin privileges its works!  –  Hughberto